# is a fractional i allowed in pumping lemma??

Tags: automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I checked the **pumping lemma** in many books(***introduction to the theory of computation Michael Sipser***) and website([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages)). they all give the same explanation:(*definition from introduction to the theory of computation, page 78*)

> **Pumping lemma**: If $A$ is a regular language, then there is a number $p$
> (the pumping length) where if $s$ is any string in $A$ of length at least
> $p$, then $s$ may be divided into three pieces, $s = xyz$, satisfying the
> following conditions:
>
> 1. for each $i \ge 0$, $xy^iz \in A$,
> 2. $|y| > 0$, and
> 3. $|xy| \le p$.

I want to know, is it possible to choose a fractional value such as $\frac{1}{3}$ for $i$?? if it is possible, how to you interpret it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  In automata theory unless indicated otherwise all the values being dealt with are natural numbers.  The $i$ indicates the length of repeated $y$ substrings and as it is a finite cardinality only natural numbers makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As a counterexample for one particular interpretation, consider an alphabet with a single symbol $a$, and the language consisting of those words that have even, positive length.

Suppose we have $x,y,z$ with the property that $x y^i z$ is in the language for all integers $i \geq 0$.

We automatically have $y = a^n$, where $n$ is the length of $y$, so we might interpret $y^{1/n} = a$.

But then $xy^{1/n}z$ is *not* in the language, since it has odd length.